# Why is IE & Edge adding to history in iframe when using replaceState

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, iframe

I'm debugging a problem with the back button not behaving correctly in IE 11 & Edge 14,15.  If you use replaceState exclusively in an iframe it should not influence the back button.  Yet it does.  It works fine in Chrome and FF.

I've created a very simple example to illustrate the problem:

http://actuary-tortoise-71770.bitballoon.com/page1

page1.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onpopstate = function(event) {
                var title = document.getElementById("title")
                title.innerText = window.location.pathname.substring(1);
                document.getElementById("console").innerHTML += "<p>onpopstate page: " + window.location.pathname + ", " + event.state + "</p>";
            };

            function next(e) {
                var title = document.getElementById("title")
                var nextTitle = title.innerText.replace(/page(\d+)/, function(m, n) { return "page" + (parseInt(n) + 1).toString() });
                title.innerText = nextTitle;
                window.history.pushState("page secret", null, nextTitle);
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1 id="title">page1</h1>
            <a href="#" onclick="next(event)">next</a>
        </div>

        <iframe src="http://propeller.api-local.prpeller.com:8081/frame1" style="margin-top: 20px; width:400px; height:200px"></iframe>

        <div id="console"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

frame1.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onpopstate = function(event) {
                var title = document.getElementById("title")
                title.innerText = window.location.pathname.substring(1);
                document.getElementById("console").innerHTML += "<p>onpopstate frame: " + window.location.pathname + ", " + event.state + "</p>";
            };

            function next(e) {
                var title = document.getElementById("title")
                var nextTitle = title.innerText.replace(/frame(\d+)/, function(m, n) { return "frame" + (parseInt(n) + 1).toString() });
                title.innerText = nextTitle;
                window.history.replaceState("frame secret", null, nextTitle);
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1 id="title">frame1</h1>
            <a href="#" onclick="next(event)">next</a>
            <div id="console"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"in IE 11,14,15"* - What do you mean by 14, 15?

Comment: IE 11, IE 14, IE 15.  I've tested it in these major IE versions (via browserstack)

Comment: There is no IE14 or IE15. Do you mean *Edge*?

Comment: Sorry, I guess this is called Edge 14 & Edge 15 instead of IE... Exact same behaviour though.

Comment: This may be the same issue - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/110886/